# Include two JavaScript files for a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, carousel

On my Magento site, I included two jQuery scripts for two kind of carousels:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery.rs.carousel.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/carousel.js') ?>"></script>
```

- `jquery.rs.carousel.js` : https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel/blob/master/src/js/jquery.rs.carousel.js
- `carousel.js` : https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-carousel/blob/master/jquery.carousel.js

My problem occurs when creating carousels. I do not know how to call a script instead of the other.

When I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.un-prod-carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

It creates me a carousel with `jquery.rs.carousel.js` (that's what I want).

But when I want to create a carousel with `carousel.js` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#prod-sim-carousel').carousel({itemsPerPage: 5, itemsPerTransition: 5});
    });
</script>
```

It does not work, because I think it calls the function of `jquery.rs.carousel.js`, and not of `carousel.js`.

Can you tell me how to call the function of a particular script?

Comment: Are you sure you're including the two carousel scripts in that order? I would expect whichever was included second to overwrite the `$.fn.carousel` of the first. In your description, the first, `jquery.rs.carousel.js` works, but the second does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best but working solution would be saving one of this scripts, e.g. carousel.js and locally change

```
$.fn.carousel = function(options) {
return this.each(function() {
var obj = Object.create(Carousel);
obj.init($(this), options);
$.data(this, 'carousel', obj);
});
};
```

to:

```
$.fn.otherCarousel = function(options) {
return this.each(function() {
var obj = Object.create(Carousel);
obj.init($(this), options);
$.data(this, 'carousel', obj);
});
};
```

And call it as $(selector).otherCarousel()